# upgrading to php 7.4 on mac osX

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am currently running php 7.3 on MacOs 10.15
Since I want to upgrade to 7.4 I tried to do it with Homebrew. Everything works fine and after updating the path if I run `php -v` I see the 7.4 version.

I tried to update apache also but here I have the issue.
I changed this line:
`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`
to this one
`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`
but now apache will not start again. The path is fine, `apachectl configtest` complains about that line I have edited but doesn't provide any meaningful information on what is wrong.

Did anyonwe face the same already? What can be the cause?

Comment: Are you sure you have the module installed in the correct place for Apache?

Comment: I start thinking that to use the homebrew installed version of PHP I also have to install apache with the same procedure... Is there a way to install php 7.4 in osX without homebrew? I haven't found any so far

Comment: I am not aware of any other way and a quick search doesn't turn up anything. I have quit running Apache and PHP on my Mac directly. I stand up Docker containers now.